# Deep linking(App indexing) in facebook

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking, android-app-indexing

I have a product page in Facebook in which I have posted many posts.Now I have created an app for my product.Now I want that when user is using facebook in android device and he click on any post on my facebook product page he should be redirected to the desired screen in my app.

How should i proceed in that?I am not able to find relevant information.

Comment: Do you want this to apply only to new links you post from now on, or also to past posts? Are you able to edit the source of the destination page for posts you have already made?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks